# Add text below font-awesome icon

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

I have a font-awesome spinner that I am testing. I would like to have a line of text above or below it that is ideally a single line (but still integrates with bootstrap). The code below presents the text below the spinner, but the text is not in a single line. Setting the `spinner-text{width}` property can put it on a single line, but it is not centered on the icon nor does it resize with bootstrap when the window size changes.

My HTML:

```
<div class="center-parent" id="spinner">
    <div class="center-container">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
        <span class="spinner-text">Please wait while we gather data from wherever...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.center-parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.center-container {
    width: 0 auto;
    height: 0 auto;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -30px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.spinner-text {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0 auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I test the spinner with the following JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spinnerVisible = false;
    $(document).ready(function () { showSpinner() });
    function showSpinner() {
        if (!spinnerVisible) {
            $("div#spinner").fadeIn("fast");
            spinnerVisible = true;
        }
        setTimeout(hideSpinner, 4000);
    };

    function hideSpinner() {
        if (spinnerVisible) {
            var spinner = $("div#spinner");
            spinner.stop();
            spinner.fadeOut("fast");
            spinnerVisible = false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

I've looked into the following and didn't find a fix:

[Font awesome icon button with label below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138745/font-awesome-icon-button-with-label-below)

[Center text above font awesome icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965311/center-text-above-font-awesome-icon)

[Centering FontAwesome icons vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642953/centering-fontawesome-icons-vertically-and-horizontally)

[centering text below font awesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540296/centering-text-below-font-awesome-icon)

Comment: Would you be able to convert your code into a working snippet or demo. Thanks

Comment: @sol here is an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rrkonyo/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it too complicated it in the example. It can be done with simpler markup and CSS flexbox, and I suggest using fixed rather than absolute position, so it can always cover the entire viewport.

```js
var spinnerVisible = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  showSpinner()
});

function showSpinner() {
  if (!spinnerVisible) {
    $("div#spinner").fadeIn("fast");
    spinnerVisible = true;
  }
  setTimeout(hideSpinner, 4000);
};

function hideSpinner() {
  if (spinnerVisible) {
    var spinner = $("div#spinner");
    spinner.stop();
    spinner.fadeOut("fast");
    spinnerVisible = false;
  }
};
```

```css
.spinner-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.spinner-container .fa {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spinner-container" id="spinner">
  <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
  <span class="spinner-text">Please wait while we gather data from ...</span>
</div>
```